# making a calculation with the elements of an elasticsearch json object, of a contract bridge score, using Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

The data is here:

```
{'took': 0, 'timed_out': False, '_shards': {'total': 5, 'successful': 5, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0}, 'hits': {'total': 16, 'max_score': 1.0, 'hits': [{'_index': 'matchpoints', '_type': 'score', '_id': '6PKYGGgBjpp4O0gQgUu5', '_score': 1.0, '_source': {'board_number': '1', 'nsp': '4', 'ewp': '11', 'contract': '3NT', 'by': 'N', 'tricks': '11', 'nsscore': '460', 'ewscore ': '0'}}, {'_index': 'matchpoints', '_type': 'score', '_id': '7_KYGGgBjpp4O0gQgUu5', '_score': 1.0, '_source': {'board_number': '2', 'nsp': '3', 'ewp': '10', 'contract': '3C', 'by': 'E', 'tricks': '10', 'nsscore': '-130', 'ewscore ': '130'}}, {'_index': 'matchpoints', '_type': 'score', '_id': '6fKYGGgBjpp4O0gQgUu5', '_score': 1.0, '_source': {'board_number': '1', 'nsp': '5', 'ewp': '12', 'contract': '3NT', 'by': 'S', 'tricks': '10', 'nsscore': '400', 'ewscore ': '0'}}, {'_index': 'matchpoints', '_type': 'score', '_id': '8_KYGGgBjpp4O0gQgUu5', '_score': 1.0, '_source': {'board_number': '2', 'nsp': '7', 'ewp': '14', 'contract': '3C', 'by': 'E', 'tricks': '10', 'nsscore': '-130', 'ewscore ': '130'}}, {'_index': 'matchpoints', '_type': 'score', '_id': '9PKYGGgBjpp4O0gQgUu5', '_score': 1.0, '_source': {'board_number': '2', 'nsp': '8', 'ewp': '15', 'contract': '3C', 'by': 'E', 'tricks': '11', 'nsscore': '-150', 'ewscore ': '150'}}, {'_index': 'matchpoints', '_type': 'score', '_id': '5fKYGGgBjpp4O0gQgUu5', '_score': 1.0, '_source': {'board_number': '1', 'nsp': '1', 'ewp': '16', 'contract': '3NT', 'by': 'N', 'tricks': '10', 'nsscore': '430', 'ewscore ': '0'}}, {'_index': 'matchpoints', '_type': 'score', '_id': '6vKYGGgBjpp4O0gQgUu5', '_score': 1.0, '_source': {'board_number': '1', 'nsp': '6', 'ewp': '13', 'contract': '4S', 'by': 'S', 'tricks': '11', 'nsscore': '480', 'ewscore ': '0'}}, {'_index': 'matchpoints', '_type': 'score', '_id': '6_KYGGgBjpp4O0gQgUu5', '_score': 1.0, '_source': {'board_number': '1', 'nsp': '7', 'ewp': '14', 'contract': '3NT', 'by': 'S', 'tricks': '8', 'nsscore': '-50', 'ewscore ': '50'}}, {'_index': 'matchpoints', '_type': 'score', '_id': '7fKYGGgBjpp4O0gQgUu5', '_score': 1.0, '_source': {'board_number': '2', 'nsp': '1', 'ewp': '16', 'contract': '6S', 'by': 'N', 'tricks': '12', 'nsscore': '1430', 'ewscore ': '0'}}, {'_index': 'matchpoints', '_type': 'score', '_id': '7vKYGGgBjpp4O0gQgUu5', '_score': 1.0, '_source': {'board_number': '2', 'nsp': '2', 'ewp': '9', 'contract': '3C', 'by': 'E', 'tricks': '10', 'nsscore': '-130', 'ewscore ': '130'}}]}}
```

The Python code, incorporating recent changes, is as follows. There is no attempt to loop through different boards as my intermediate attempt. This data is just produced by a search all query.

```
@application.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    search = {"query": {"match_all": {}}}
    resp = es.search(index="matchpoints", doc_type="score", body = search)
    rows = extract_rows(resp)
    for board in rows:
        scores = score_board(board)
        report(scores)
        print(report(scores))
    return 'ok'

def extract_rows(resp):                                                                                                          
    """Extract the rows for the board from the query response."""                                                                
    # Based on the data structure provided by the OP.                                                          
    rows = [row["_source"] for row in resp["hits"]["hits"]]
    # We want to return the group the data by board number
    # so that we can score each board.                                                                       
    keyfunc = lambda row: int(row['board_number'])                                                                               
    rows.sort(key=keyfunc)                                                                                                       
    for _, group in itertools.groupby(rows, keyfunc):                                                                            
        yield list(group)

def compute_mp(scores, score):
    """Compute the match point score for a pair."""
    mp_score = sum(v for k, v in scores.items() if score > k) * 2
    # The pair's own score will always compare equal - remove it.
    mp_score += sum(v for k, v in scores.items() if score == k) - 1
    return mp_score

def score_board(tables):
    """Build the scores for each pair."""
    scores = []
    top = 2 * (len(tables) - 1)
    # Store the scores for each N-S partnership.
    ns_scores = collections.Counter(int(table["nsscore"]) for table in tables)
    # Build the output for each pair.
    for table in tables:
        output = {
            "board": table["board_number"],
            "nsp": table["nsp"],
            "ewp": table["ewp"],
        }
        ns_score = int(table["nsscore"])
        ns_mp_score = compute_mp(ns_scores, ns_score)
        output["ns_mp_score"] = ns_mp_score
        ew_mp_score = top - ns_mp_score
        output["ew_mp_score"] = ew_mp_score
        scores.append(output)
    return scores

# Replace this function with one that adds the rows to
# the new search index
def report(scores):
    """Print the scores."""
    for row in scores:
        print(row)
```

which produces, as before, the correct dictionary where the scoring is correct but there are duplication of results and too many lines. Also, there are two instances of "None" and I don't know where that comes from. :

```
{'board': '1', 'nsp': '4', 'ewp': '11', 'ns_mp_score': 6, 'ew_mp_score': 2}
{'board': '1', 'nsp': '5', 'ewp': '12', 'ns_mp_score': 2, 'ew_mp_score': 6}
{'board': '1', 'nsp': '1', 'ewp': '16', 'ns_mp_score': 4, 'ew_mp_score': 4}
{'board': '1', 'nsp': '6', 'ewp': '13', 'ns_mp_score': 8, 'ew_mp_score': 0}
{'board': '1', 'nsp': '7', 'ewp': '14', 'ns_mp_score': 0, 'ew_mp_score': 8}
{'board': '1', 'nsp': '4', 'ewp': '11', 'ns_mp_score': 6, 'ew_mp_score': 2}
{'board': '1', 'nsp': '5', 'ewp': '12', 'ns_mp_score': 2, 'ew_mp_score': 6}
{'board': '1', 'nsp': '1', 'ewp': '16', 'ns_mp_score': 4, 'ew_mp_score': 4}
{'board': '1', 'nsp': '6', 'ewp': '13', 'ns_mp_score': 8, 'ew_mp_score': 0}
{'board': '1', 'nsp': '7', 'ewp': '14', 'ns_mp_score': 0, 'ew_mp_score': 8}
None
{'board': '2', 'nsp': '3', 'ewp': '10', 'ns_mp_score': 4, 'ew_mp_score': 4}
{'board': '2', 'nsp': '7', 'ewp': '14', 'ns_mp_score': 4, 'ew_mp_score': 4}
{'board': '2', 'nsp': '8', 'ewp': '15', 'ns_mp_score': 0, 'ew_mp_score': 8}
{'board': '2', 'nsp': '1', 'ewp': '16', 'ns_mp_score': 8, 'ew_mp_score': 0}
{'board': '2', 'nsp': '2', 'ewp': '9', 'ns_mp_score': 4, 'ew_mp_score': 4}
{'board': '2', 'nsp': '3', 'ewp': '10', 'ns_mp_score': 4, 'ew_mp_score': 4}
{'board': '2', 'nsp': '7', 'ewp': '14', 'ns_mp_score': 4, 'ew_mp_score': 4}
{'board': '2', 'nsp': '8', 'ewp': '15', 'ns_mp_score': 0, 'ew_mp_score': 8}
{'board': '2', 'nsp': '1', 'ewp': '16', 'ns_mp_score': 8, 'ew_mp_score': 0}
{'board': '2', 'nsp': '2', 'ewp': '9', 'ns_mp_score': 4, 'ew_mp_score': 4}
None
```

The scoring is correct but there are, again, multiple cases of duplication of the same pairs' results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will calculate the scores.  The code is fairly straightforward.

Rather than iterate over the input dictionary to compute the scores for each pair, the the North-South scores are stored in a [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instance that keeps a count of the number of pairs that made each score.  This makes it easier to compute the match point score for each pair - we just double the number of lower scores made and add the number of equal scores made, minus one to account for the score of the current partnership.

```
import collections                                                                                                               
import itertools                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    


def extract_rows(resp):                                                                                                          
    """Extract the rows for the board from the query response."""                                                                
    # Based on the data structure provided by the OP.                                                          
    rows = [row["_source"] for row in resp["hits"]["hits"]]
    # We want to return the group the data by board number
    # so that we can score each board.                                                                       
    keyfunc = lambda row: int(row['board_number'])                                                                               
    rows.sort(key=keyfunc)                                                                                                       
    for _, group in itertools.groupby(rows, keyfunc):                                                                            
        yield list(group)


def compute_mp(scores, score):
    """Compute the match point score for a pair."""
    mp_score = sum(v for k, v in scores.items() if score > k) * 2
    # The pair's own score will always compare equal - remove it.
    mp_score += sum(v for k, v in scores.items() if score == k) - 1
    return mp_score


def score_board(tables):
    """Build the scores for each pair."""
    scores = []

    # Store the scores for each N-S partnership.
    ns_scores = collections.Counter(int(table["nsscore"]) for table in tables)
    # The top score is (2 * number of tables) - 2, then reduced by one for each 
    # equal top score.
    top = 2 * (len(tables) - 1) - (ns_scores[max(ns_scores)] - 1)
    # Build the output for each pair.
    for table in tables:
        output = {
            "board": table["board_number"],
            "nsp": table["nsp"],
            "ewp": table["ewp"],
        }
        ns_score = int(table["nsscore"])
        ns_mp_score = compute_mp(ns_scores, ns_score)
        output["ns_mp_score"] = ns_mp_score
        ew_mp_score = top - ns_mp_score
        output["ew_mp_score"] = ew_mp_score
        scores.append(output)
    return scores

# Replace this function with one that adds the rows to
# the new search index
def report(scores):
    """Print the scores."""
    for row in scores:
        print(row)
```

Running the code:

```
rows = extract_rows(resp)
scores = [score for rows in extract_rows(resp) for score in score_board(rows)]
report(scores)
```

Produces this output:

```
{'board': '1', 'nsp': '4', 'ewp': '11', 'ns_mp_score': 6, 'ew_mp_score': 2}
{'board': '1', 'nsp': '5', 'ewp': '12', 'ns_mp_score': 2, 'ew_mp_score': 6}
{'board': '1', 'nsp': '1', 'ewp': '16', 'ns_mp_score': 4, 'ew_mp_score': 4}
{'board': '1', 'nsp': '6', 'ewp': '13', 'ns_mp_score': 8, 'ew_mp_score': 0}
{'board': '1', 'nsp': '7', 'ewp': '14', 'ns_mp_score': 0, 'ew_mp_score': 8}
{'board': '2', 'nsp': '3', 'ewp': '10', 'ns_mp_score': 4, 'ew_mp_score': 4}
{'board': '2', 'nsp': '7', 'ewp': '14', 'ns_mp_score': 4, 'ew_mp_score': 4}
{'board': '2', 'nsp': '8', 'ewp': '15', 'ns_mp_score': 0, 'ew_mp_score': 8}
{'board': '2', 'nsp': '1', 'ewp': '16', 'ns_mp_score': 8, 'ew_mp_score': 0}
{'board': '2', 'nsp': '2', 'ewp': '9', 'ns_mp_score': 4, 'ew_mp_score': 4}
```

Comment: Absolutely amazing, thank you. Do you play bridge? Seems you do. This has anticipated other difficulties that I am expecting to deal with later in this project so thank you for that too. Would you like the bounty?

Comment: I used to play, but it's been a while now.  Obviously I'd appreciate the bounty, upvotes etc but best you wait until the end of the period (the system may enforce that anyway) - someone else might have an even better solution!

Comment: right ho we'll wait but, as you say, may not have a choice. Meantime I will tick your answer.

Comment: I made a small change - moved the multiplication out of the first `sum` in `compute_mp` so that we only need to multiply once, rather than multiplying each value.  This is more efficient, though it doesn't matter too much unless you are computing a lot of results.

Comment: I have edited my question to include new difficulties.

Comment: I'll take a look tomorrow, but note that you have actually edited my answer :-).  Perhaps you could edit your question to clarify the structure of the data that you get from elastic search (in particular how it is structured when we have more than one board) and the structure that you want for the output.

Comment: dear me, sorry! I will edit my question later this evening!

Comment: I've changed the code to handle your requirement.  Your problem seems to have been that you were creating a new value of `resp` in the middle of your loop.  You might want to revert your edit to your question as it's obscured the original question - just add the sample data and the requirement to handle multiple boards to the original.

Comment: thank you! Just seen this, I will test it later. I have bitten off way more than I can chew here .... thanks for your help.

Comment: I have now tested it and the duplication problem, although less severe, still exists. I have edited the question with new results generated by the new approach you kindly suggested.

Comment: You are running the report function twice

Comment: thank you. I removed the print(report(scores)) and varied the position of return "ok" and it still does not work correctly. The code, this time, generates only half the results. I thank you for the beautiful solution and work you have put in to this ... I am stuck!

Comment: I've changed the 'running the code' example to collect the scores in a list comprehension.  It's less readable than the explicit `for` loop imo, but should make it easier to review the output.

Answer (score 0):

This NOT my work, it is the work of "rvs" but as this is the answer I am looking for I will post it here so that may help others.

```
scores = {}
for row in arr["hits"]["hits"]:
  nsp = row["_source"]["nsp"]
  nsscore = row["_source"]["nsscore"]
  scores[nsp] = nsscore

input_scores = {}

def calculate_score(pair, scores):
    score = 0
    for p in scores:
        if p == pair:
            continue
        if scores[p] < scores[pair]:
            score += 2  # win
        elif scores[p] == scores[pair]:
            score += 1
    return score


board_num = arr["hits"]["total"]
top = (board_num - 1) * 2
result_score = {}
for row in arr["hits"]["hits"]:
  nsp = row["_source"]["nsp"]
  ewp = row["_source"]["ewp"]
  res = calculate_score(nsp, scores)
  ew_mp_score = top - res
  result_score.update({'nsp':nsp, 'ns_mp_score': res, 'ewp': ewp, 'ew_mp_score': ew_mp_score})
  print(result_score)
```

Thank you.